# GET a full url from HTACCESS file

Tags: .htaccess

I have this code:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?path=$1 [L,QSA,NC]
```

The problem is that `$_GET['path']` doesn't gets the full URL, only what after the first slash. For example. I want that when user will enter to example.com/hello, him to be redirected (without rewriting the url) to `example.com/index.php?path=example.com/hello`. How can I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond $1 !^index\.php
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?path=%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [L,QSA]
```